# Conditional joining in Postgres using levenshtein

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables lets say Table A and Table B...

I want to query these two tables so that I can check to see if two columns in the tables say col1 and col2 are similar and show them.

Something like:

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col2  
FROM A INNER JOIN B 
ON LEVENSHTEIN(A.col1, B.col2) < 2;
```

Ultimately I want to also get rid of all the white spaces within and just look at the characters within the columns so

if col1 values where `{g o o d, b a d,}`
and col2 had `{good,bad}`

I would like those to be matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT A.col1, B.col2  
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B 
     ON LEVENSHTEIN(replace(A.col1, ' ', ''), replace(B.col2, ' ', '')) < 2;
```

Comment: @user3210458 . . . This structure works to solve the query.  You have a different problem.  How large are the tables?